# get css pixels using innerWidth and devicePixelRation

Tags: javascript, css

This question has been asked for but I'm coming across a very different issue.

The `devicePixelRatio` is `3` and `window.innerWidth` is `780` reported in my browser window.

I have chosen a device iPhone 12 Pro (390x844) with logical width to be 390 in chrome developer tools which can be calculated `window.innerWidth/2`.

The existing answers suggest dividing the `window.innerWidth/devicePixelRatio` (3) which will put me way off course.

Clearly the formula is wrong so What's the reliable way to calculate logical css pixels